# ViewPager height-adjust with AnimateOnLayoutChanges glitches to different page

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-animation

I have a ViewPager that is tacked onto the bottom of a header bar. Upon reaching the final page, the header bar actually shrinks to Visibility.GONE and so the viewpager page occupies the whole page. This isn't the part I need help with, but instead having it AnimateLayoutChanges = true on the layout file, it glitches to another page instead of staying on the same page.

Switcher code looks like this (called onClick of a tab, or on PageChange)

```
private void switchTab(Integer tabNumber){
    if (tabNumber != currentTab) {
        currentTab = tabNumber;
        for (int x=0; x<tab_holder.getChildCount(); x++){
            final int pos = x;
            FacilityTab tab = tabs.get(pos);
            if (x != tabNumber){
                tab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_msg_title));
            }else{
                tab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_bar_pressed));
            }
        }
        try {
            tab_controller.smoothScrollTo(tab_holder.getChildAt(tabNumber).getLeft() - 100, 0);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (tabNumber == (tab_holder.getChildCount() - 1)){
        tab_controller.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        headerBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pager.setCurrentItem(tabNumber);
    }else{
        tab_controller.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        headerBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/background_color">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/header_bar"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/back_arrow"
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:padding="18dp"
            android:tint="@color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/chat_small"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />

    </TableRow>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_bar"
        android:id="@+id/tab_controller"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:background="@color/text_msg_title"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tab_holder">

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tab_controller" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:id="@+id/notification_view"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/varbutton"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@color/notification_green"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/notification_bell"
            android:padding="12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Username"
            android:id="@+id/notification_title"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:textSize="24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="User&apos;s new message"
            android:id="@+id/notification_detail"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/notification_title"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/varbutton"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/floating_button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/msgicon"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:padding="16dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

(Pictures edited for privacy)

This is what a normal page looks like...
[image: Here's a normal tab page]

This is what happens when you TRY to swipe to the right, it swipes over then glitches back to this position with no header.
[image: Here's after swiping]

But if you swipe right again from that glitched view, it'll do it properly. Why is it glitching and hanging up after successfully swiping all the way over?
[image: Here's after swiping again, and the end goal.]

Comment: you need to put some code how you have created your viewpager etc, with screen shots its difficult to understand the problem

Comment: Heard! Added some context and code, let me know if you're curious about anything else.

Comment: @surya any info you can help with?

Comment: can you print the tabNumber when u call setCurrentItem on viewpager and print the item for the Fullpageview which you are setting

Comment: @surya It definitely is printing the tab it SHOULD be on, with no duplication or reversal (though the visual would suggest otherwise)